# How to get live local date & time of the searched city using Open weather API

Tags: javascript, openweathermap, weather-api

I have created a weather project using open weather API: https://openweathermap.org/current?fbclid=IwAR1SVc9zn9uXaZWLmJA9lYEeZvUc1s_kR68RFadWuIwd8yBjIyJ7zsVMKkE

I have added all the API parameters to my code.

However, I also want to fetch the **live** local date and time for the city that is being searched.

For example, when the user searches "Athens" it displays something like this:

> Saturday 15/1/2022 16:24:03 (I want the seconds to change **live** every second that passes)

**MY  CODE:**

*javascript and HTML scripts insert*

```js
let weather = {
  apiKey: "XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX",
  fetchWeather: function (city) {
    fetch(
      "https://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?q=" +
        city +
        "&units=metric&lang=en&appid=" +
        this.apiKey
    )
  
      .then((response) => {
        if (!response.ok) {
          alert("No weather found.");
          throw new Error("No weather found.");
        }
        return response.json();
      })
      .then((data) => this.displayWeather(data));
  },
  
  //fetching the API parameters:
  displayWeather: function (data) {
    const { name } = data;
    const { lon } = data.coord;
    const { lat } = data.coord;
    const { icon, description } = data.weather[0];
    const { feels_like } = data.main;
    const { temp, humidity } = data.main;
    const {temp_min} = data.main;
    const {temp_max} = data.main;
    const { pressure } = data.main;
    const { speed } = data.wind;
    const { deg } = data.wind;
    const { visibility } = data;
    const { all } = data.clouds;
    const { gust } = data.wind;
    const {timezone} = data;
    const { sunrise } = data.sys;
    const { sunset } = data.sys;

  
//Displaying the results:
    document.querySelector(".city").innerText = "Weather: " + name;
    document.querySelector(".lon").innerText = "Longitude: " + lon;
    document.querySelector(".lat").innerText = "Latitude: " + lat;
    document.querySelector(".icon").src =
      "https://openweathermap.org/img/wn/" + icon + ".png";
    document.querySelector(".description").innerText = description;
    document.querySelector(".temp").innerText = temp + "°C";
    document.querySelector(".feels-like").innerText = "Temperature feels like: " + feels_like + "°C";
    document.querySelector(".temp_min").innerText = "Minimum Temperature: " + temp_min + "°C";
    document.querySelector(".temp_max").innerText = "Maximum Temperature: " + temp_max + "°C";
    document.querySelector(".humidity").innerText =
      "Humidity: " + humidity + "%";
    document.querySelector(".visibility").innerText = "Visibility: " + visibility + " meters";
    document.querySelector(".cloudiness").innerText = "Cloudiness: " + all + "%";
    document.querySelector(".pressure").innerText = "Atmospheric Pressure: " + pressure + " hPa";
    document.querySelector(".wind").innerText =
      "Wind speed: " + speed + " km/h";
    document.querySelector(".wind-deg").innerText = "Wind degrees: " + deg + "°";
    document.querySelector(".wind-gust").innerText = "Wind gust: " + gust + " m/s";
    document.querySelector(".sunrise").innerText = "Sunrise: " + window.moment(sunrise * 1000).format('HH:mm a');
    document.querySelector(".sunset").innerText = "Sunset: " + window.moment(sunset * 1000).format('HH:mm a');
    document.querySelector(".weather").classList.remove("loading");
    document.body.style.backgroundImage =
      "url('https://source.unsplash.com/1600x900/?')"; 
  },

  
  search: function () {
    this.fetchWeather(document.querySelector(".search-bar").value);
  },
};

document.querySelector(".search button").addEventListener("click", function () {
  weather.search();
});

document
  .querySelector(".search-bar")
  .addEventListener("keyup", function (event) {
    if (event.key == "Enter") {
      weather.search();
    }
  });
//Displaying Athens weather on page load
weather.fetchWeather("Athens");
```

```html
<script src="https://momentjs.com/downloads/moment.js"></script>
 <!-- script to convert sunrise and sunset times to time format and on the local time of the searched city -->
 <script src="./script.js" defer></script>
 <!-- local script -->
```

What modifications should I do to my code?

**NOTE: I want the LIVE date and time if possible.**

Comment: do you have a backend with this?

Comment: There is a free public weather api called **weatherDB**, which is more easy and simple to implement. Site: https://weatherdbi.herokuapp.com/.  This will **give current time and day with the response**

Answer (score 2):

You can try out [Time API](https://dev.timeanddate.com/docs/time/) 
With this API, you can **get current time** and **time zone information for any location on Earth**, **convert time zones** and list **all Daylight Saving Time (DST) changes** in a specific location.

According to the documentation (implementation with cURL):

```
$ ACCESSKEY="<Your Access Key>"
$ SECRETKEY="<Your Secret Key>"
$ curl -G \
    --data-urlencode "version=3" \
    --data-urlencode "prettyprint=1" \
    --data-urlencode "accesskey=$ACCESSKEY" \
    --data-urlencode "secretkey=$SECRETKEY" \
    --data-urlencode "placeid=norway/oslo" \
    https://api.xmltime.com/timeservice
```

Comment: I am not sure how to implement this in Javascript. You can definitely explore this API

Answer (score 0):

fetching the API parameters
(displayWeather)

```
 const {timezone} = data;
 const {dt} = data;
 const dateTime = new Date(dt * 1000);
 const toUtc = dateTime.getTime() + dateTime.getTimezoneOffset() * 60000;
 const currentLocalTime = toUtc + 1000 * timezone;
 const selectedDate = new Date(currentLocalTime);

 const date = selectedDate.toLocaleString("en-GB", {
      day: "numeric",
      weekday: "long",
      month: "long",
 });
 const year = selectedDate.toLocaleString("en-GB", {
      year: "numeric",
 });
 const hour = selectedDate.toLocaleString("en-GB", {
      hour: "2-digit",
      minute: "2-digit",
      hour12: false,
 });
 return `${date} ${year} ${hour}`; //Thursday, 21 July 2022 18:14
```